# reading matrix from text file and use numbers of one column in C++

Tags: c++

I am a beginner
I am using with CORSIKA software. cosika's outputs are text files with 8 or 7 column and more than 2000 row(like matrix) .
Arrays of this matrix are number in Scientific notation like fallowing image

```
2.11285E+05  2.00000E+01  1.30714E+05  7.35000E+00  1.00000E+00  1.10000E+04  0.00000E+00
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00
0.00000E+00 -2.70000E+00  1.00000E+03  1.00000E+03  1.00000E+00  1.00000E+00  3.00000E-01
3.00000E-01  3.00000E-03  3.00000E-03  6.37132E+08  6.00000E+05  2.00000E+06  0.00000E+00
0.00000E+00  4.58060E-02  5.73090E-01  5.28304E-02  2.50000E+00  2.07000E+00  8.20000E+00
1.00000E-01  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  1.00002E+00  9.67266E-03  1.00000E+00  5.75129E-04
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  3.77000E+01  1.53287E-04  9.38642E+00  2.00000E-03  2.99792E+10
```

I want to read data in 7th column and calculate some parameters like average, maximum, minimum  in one column.

I have this code to read and display text file but i dont know how use numbers and calculate some parameters.

```
#include<iostream.h>        
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *k;
    char c;
    k = fopen("c:\\fff.txt", "r");
    c = getc(k);
    while(c != EOF)
    {
         cout << c;
         c = getc(k);
    }
    getch();
    fclose(k);
    return 0;
}
```

please help me.
thanks

Comment: If you are using C++ it is easier to use an fstream. See: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/ for an example

Comment: Did you get the license place of the guy that stole your tab key?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::string line;
    std::istringstream iss;

    while (std::getline(file >> std::ws, line))
    {
        float f;

        iss.str(line);
        while (iss >> f)
            ;

        // f is equal to the 7th row by this line
    }
}
```

Depending on your needs, `f` can be local to the scope of the while loop or otherwise.